# get extended additional properties with graphclient

Tags: .net, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to receive a user from Microsoft Graph using the graphclient. the last property is an extended property that has been replicated across from on premise AD and i dont know how to reference it?

i can select the property using a normal url format Graph request using Graph Explorer so i know it is there, just not sure of the syntax using the graphclient?

```
        var user = await graphClient.Me.Request()
            .Select(u => new {
                u.DisplayName,
                u.Mail,
                u.UserPrincipalName,
                u.Department,
                u.OnPremisesSamAccountName,
                u.OfficeLocation,
                u.GivenName,
                u.Surname,
                u.JobTitle,
                 u.??["extension_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_PersonID"]
            })
            .GetAsync();
```

Comment: If you're talking about reading extensions then you can use the following code:

GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

var user = await graphClient.Me
 .Request()
 .Expand("extensions")
 .Select("id,displayName,mail")
 .GetAsync();

Comment: @Dev, .Expand("extensions") function works, but it doesn't bring all additional properties assigned to it. instead it only gets properties mentioned in Select function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try the below code

```
try
        {


            List<Option> requestOptions = new ArrayList<Option>();

            requestOptions.Add(new QueryOption("$select", "extension_xxx_FavouriteSeason,DisplayName,Mail,UserPrincipalName"));



            var user = await graphClient.Users["xxxx"].Request(requestOptions)
     
            .GetAsync();



            Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user));
              
        }
   catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
```

Comment: It correctly provides additional data as mentioned in Select

Comment: Can we get all additional data without specifying them explicitely?